# Xcode Reskit after mapping i get null value in NSLog and when assign to label

Tags: xcode, restkit

I got another issue when I connect to a webservice using RestKit.

When I used (`RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/*", RKLogLevelTrace);`) it is ok. There is data mapped to the variable. But when I try to display it in a label or when I use NSlog I get a Null value

Here is some code of my file

```
NSString* _Biography ;
NSString* _Courses ;

NSString* _CoursesNames ;

NSString* _DOB ;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Biography ;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Courses ;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* CoursesNames ;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* DOB ;



@synthesize Biography =_Biography ;
@synthesize Courses=_Courses ;
@synthesize CoursesNames=_CoursesNames ;
@synthesize DOB=_DOB ;

[mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes: 
 @"Biography",@"Biography",
 @"Courses",@"Courses",
 @"CoursesNames", @"CoursesNames",
 @"DOB",@"DOB"
```

this is a log from (`RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/*", RKLogLevelTrace);`)

```
 Biography = "Rita u .";
 Courses = "Math”
 CoursesNames = " Math001";
 DOB = "Ssss";
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have found the solution, can we see part of code of your callback function ?

Maybe you don't use correctly retuned objects.